# Storing ints in Arrays without knowing the length the user will specify(as a string, not an int!?)

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, integer

I want my program (java) to ask the user how many cups he wants (e.g. 4), then ask them how many sugars he wants in each cup. I would store them as an array.. but truthfully have almost no idea on how to go about it.. I just need a starting point!
An example:

```
How many sugars in cup 1? 0

How many sugars in cup 2? 1

How many sugars in cup 3? 3

How many sugars in cup 4? 1
```

So far I have something like this:(The user would have previously typed how many cups they want).

```
int[] sugarList = new int [cupsWanted];
while(cupsWanted > 0) {
    System.out.println("How many sugars in cup " + shotlist[0++] + "?");
}
```

I feel like I am stuck in a rut and not sure if I am on the right track.. any help would be great!! Thanks

Comment: Why dont you replace array with a list

Comment: *"(The user would have previously typed how many cups they want)"* Okay. So parse that string to an int and use it for `capsWanted`.

Comment: `ArrayList` should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title:

Don't use an array to store it, use an `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` will automatically resize as you add items.

```
List<Integer> sugarList = new ArrayList<>();
```

To answer the question in the body - you need to parse the String into an Integer using:

```
Integer.valueOf(theStringEntered);
```

Comment: I think I also said the same thing

Comment: @Saurabh You only gave a vague indication what to use and didnt explain how to use it, nor did you answer the question in the body, this is a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers- new to this and struggling! So I've now got this:
      List<Integer> SugarList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

             Integer.valueOf(cupsWanted);

             int i = 0;

  while (i < SugarList.size())

                         {

      System.out.println(SugarList.get(i));

      i++;

                         }

Comment: But now I need to get it to 'step through' the array and ask how many sugars the user wants in each cup, while storing their answers. so I store their answers in a separate array or the as part of the SugarList array?